# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases in repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I keep getting the same error again and again trying to do a one way repeated measures ANOVA using the anova_test in rstatix package. Here is my data
https://github.com/gyrusrectus/stackquery/blob/master/s2.csv and code

```
anova_test(data=s2, dv = mean_score, wid = id, within = station)
```

I want to compare the mean scores of candidates across three different task stations. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `anova_test`. It throws an error if your data frame contains variables that aren't in your model. If you drop them it works as expected:

```r
s2 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gyrusrectus/stackquery/master/s2.csv")
s2 <- s2[,c(1, 2, 7)]

anova_test(data = s2, dv = mean_score, wid = cand_id, within = station)
#> 
#> ANOVA Table (type III tests)
#> 
#> $ANOVA
#>    Effect DFn DFd   F        p p<.05   ges
#> 1 station   2  42 8.8 0.000643     * 0.157
#> 
#> $`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
#>    Effect     W     p p<.05
#> 1 station 0.859 0.219      
#> 
#> $`Sphericity Corrections`
#>    Effect   GGe      DF[GG] p[GG] p[GG]<.05  HFe     DF[HF]    p[HF] p[HF]<.05
#> 1 station 0.876 1.75, 36.81 0.001         * 0.95 1.9, 39.89 0.000819         *
```